# Why Windows Phone YouTube does not load URL

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, youtube, webbrowser-control

Today, I've tried to use WebBrowser control on Windows Phone 7 to get YouTube video.

1. browsing to: http://m.youtube.com
2. tapping on video on WP7: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6YmH5VENszY (This link is from Firefox browser)
3. WP7 only shows URL: http://m.youtube.com/?reload=16&rdm=ysu4q22f#

I read about license problems between Google and Microsoft http://blogs.technet.com/b/microsoft_on_the_issues/archive/2013/08/15/the-limits-of-google-s-openness.aspx

Is that the current issue or is there a solution in technical view?

Comment: Some videos don't support mobile when viewing the website - and if you were making an app to play YouTube videos, you would use the API which provides access to different versions of the video and its meta data.